# Building python with openssl support

Tags: compiling, python, openssl

I have the following directory structure:

```
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~/mini-bin$ la
2to3               cpp-5.3.0            gcov-5.3.0           grmid-5.3.0         objcopy-2.25.1    python3.5-config      .sources
2to3-3.5           elfedit-2.25.1       gcov-tool-5.3.0      grmiregistry-5.3.0  objdump-2.25.1    python3.5m            strings-2.25.1
addr2line-2.25.1   g++-5.3.0            gfortran-5.3.0       gserialver-5.3.0    pydoc             python3.5m-config     strip-2.25.1
aot-compile-5.3.0  gappletviewer-5.3.0  gij-5.3.0            gtnameserv-5.3.0    pydoc3            python3-config        x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-c++-5.3.0
ar-2.25.1          gc-analyze-5.3.0     gjar-5.3.0           idle                pydoc3.5          python-config         x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++-5.3.0
.archives          gcc-5.3.0            gjarsigner-5.3.0     idle3               python            pyvenv                x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-5.3.0
as-2.25.1          gcc-ar-5.3.0         gjavah-5.3.0         idle3.5             python2           pyvenv-3.5            x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-5.3.0
bash               gcc-nm-5.3.0         gkeytool-5.3.0       jcf-dump-5.3.0      python2.7         ranlib-2.25.1         x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-5.3.0
.binaries          gcc-ranlib-5.3.0     gnative2ascii-5.3.0  jv-convert-5.3.0    python2.7-config  readelf-2.25.1        x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-5.3.0
.build             gcj-5.3.0            gorbd-5.3.0          ld-2.25.1           python2-config    rebuild-gcj-db-5.3.0  x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcj-5.3.0
c++-5.3.0          gcj-dbtool-5.3.0     gprof-2.25.1         ld.bfd-2.25.1       python3           size-2.25.1           x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gfortran-5.3.0
c++filt-2.25.1     gcjh-5.3.0           grmic-5.3.0          nm-2.25.1           python3.5         smtpd.py
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~/mini-bin$ la .sources/
bash-4.4-beta  binutils-2.25.1  boost_1_60_0  gcc-5.3.0  Python-2.7.11  Python-3.5.1
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~/mini-bin$ la .build/
bash-4.4-beta  binutils-2.25.1  boost_1_60_0  gcc-5.3.0  Python-2.7.11  Python-3.5.1
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~/mini-bin$ la .binaries/
bash-4.4-beta  binutils-2.25.1  boost_1_60_0  gcc-5.3.0  Python-2.7.11  Python-3.5.1
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~/mini-bin$
```

Generally, tar balls go in `.archives`, unpacked sources go in `.sources`, building happens in `.build`, and the final binaries are store in `.binaries`. I then symlink the binaries from `.binaries` to `~/mini-bin`which is on my $PATH.I know its a weird workflow, but it works for me. Anyways, I am looking to rebuild python-2.7.11 (and 3.4.0, but am starting with 2.7.11) from source. It builds fine on my system, but I need it to build with ncurses, readline, ssl, etc support. Do I have to compile these libraries from source? If so, where would I put the libraries? How do I tell python to build with them. Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: Alright. I'll try that then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to elementary OS. As proposed, try it at another Stackexchange site, please.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to build 3.9.1 on Ubuntu 20.10

Following the dependency hints here:

https://devguide.python.org/setup/#install-dependencies

specifically, I installed 3.9.0 from the repositories, enabled source repositories, and then:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3.9
```

and then using this for the configure step:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" ./configure --enable-optimizations
```

means I build python without ssl errors, which is encouraging.

Without the LDFLAGS prefix, build gave ssl failures.

However,

```
make test
```

still shows fails for the ssl tests, although the module imports.

Answer (score -1):

Just focusing on ssl alone the answer are many:

https://serverfault.com/questions/353128/recompiling-python-with-ssl-support-on-ubuntu

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-May/027866.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409092/coredump-when-compiling-python-with-a-custom-openssl-version

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/installing-python-with-ssl-support-in-local

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516956/how-to-compile-python-2-4-6-with-ssl-readline-and-zlib-on-debian-lenny

https://bugs.python.org/issue21541

And no - definitely you don't need the original SSL sources, just "apt-get install libssl-dev" will do.